# CSS animation - черные квадраты

Tags: google-chrome, css-animation

Последнее время, на некоторых сайтах, появились, мигающие в хаотичном порядке, черные квадраты. Причем, не всегда они есть. Поначалу думал, что это какие-нибудь баги рекламные.  Однако, решил побаловаться с CSS-анимацией, и вот увидел их у себя на тестовой, локальной, страничке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#bodyWrap{
.clear();
 width: 3000px;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
 background-size: 2500px  100%;
 background-position:0px top; 
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 animation: bg;
 animation-duration: 90s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;

}

@keyframes bg{
0% {
 background-position:0px top; 
}
100% {
 background-position:-1500px top; 
}
}
```

Пользуюсь Хромом Версия 66.0.3359.181 . В Мозилле, вроде бы этого нет.
Почему появляются эти квадраты? Связаны ли они только с браузером или еще имеет значение мощность компьютера?

Comment: а где это можно увидить ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский,  это у меня, локально. Возможно у Вас такого и нет.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, .. может Вы интересовались, где это я в сети видел) - здесь только что было -  https://sport.ua/  )

Comment: Видел такую хрень. Есть подозрение, что это глюк Chrome. У них нелады с последней версией. Ещё и элементы в dev tools грузятся через раз.

Comment: у меня в опере на стаковерфлоу тоже было - я на мете пост создавал - скрины выкладывал - это глюк браузера